# How can i push some fragment to back_stack without show them to user

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I want to show detail and  push some fragment to backstack fragment Manager android without show these fragment to user,  when notification clicked .

I think showing my purpose in code is better . I want something like below code `(note: this code not work and just replace last fragment)`
thanks in Advance.

```
    fun ShowFactorDetailWithBackStack(){
    popEveryFragment()
    val main=MainFragment.newInstance()
    val club=ClubDetailFragment.newInstance()
    val factor =FactorDetailFragment.newInstance()
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.slide_in_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right
        ).replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,main, HOME)
        .setMaxLifecycle(main, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        .addToBackStack(HOME)
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, club, DETAIL_CLUB)
        .setMaxLifecycle(club, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        .addToBackStack(DETAIL_CLUB)
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, factor, DETAIL)
        .setMaxLifecycle(factor, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        .addToBackStack(DETAIL)
        .commit()
}
```

Comment: have you tried this code and it doesnt work ?

Comment: @LenaBru yeah i try this and doesn't work

Comment: can you describe the result you are seeing ?

Comment: @LenaBru with this code  just factor fragment  will be added and when click  on back button, app will be exit .

Comment: try removing    all the     .setMaxLifecycle(factor, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
I've never heard of this setting and after reading about it, i think it's unnecessary in your case

Comment: @LenaBru I Removed all these line from code but show no different result :(